# Build problem on Apache Cordova Android app with Firebase and ordova-plugin-firebase

Tags: android, firebase, cordova, push-notification, visual-studio-2017

i need an help about Firebase and Cordova plugin: [cordova-plugin-firebase](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/blob/master/docs/API.md). 
So I use visual studio 2017 and I need to create an android project with push notifications. So I've installed this plugin and after that, when i try to run device i receive this error from visual studio 2017.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:606) Mivebo      1   
Error       Failed to notify ProjectEvaluationListener.afterEvaluate(), but primary configuration failure takes precedence. Mivebo      1   
Error       java.lang.IllegalStateException: buildToolsVersion is not specified.    Mivebo      1   
Error        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:176) Mivebo      1   
Error        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10$1.call(BasePlugin.java:572)  Mivebo      1   
Error        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10$1.call(BasePlugin.java:569)  Mivebo      1   
Error        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:55) Mivebo      1   
Error        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:47) Mivebo      1   
Error        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.execute(BasePlugin.java:568) Mivebo      1   
Error        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.execute(BasePlugin.java:565) Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:93) Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:82) Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:44) Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:79) Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:30) Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)    Mivebo      1   
Error        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)    Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:67)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:61)  Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:529)  Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:90)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:42)  Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$2.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:125)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:122)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99) Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93) Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)  Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:82)  Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)  Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28) Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43) Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28) Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:81)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:46)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37) Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34) Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)    Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)    Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60) Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72) Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41) Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246) Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)  Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) Mivebo      1   
Error        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) Mivebo      1   
Error        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)   Mivebo      1   
Error       FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.    Mivebo      1   
Error       * Where:    Mivebo      1   
Error       Build file 'C:\projects\Mivebo\Mivebo\platforms\android\build.gradle' line: 45  Mivebo      1   
Error       * What went wrong:  Mivebo      1   
Error       A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.   Mivebo      1   
Error       > Could not find method google() for arguments [] on repository container.  Mivebo      1   
Error       * Try:  Mivebo      1   
Error       Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.  Mivebo      1   
Error       Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:   Mivebo      1   
Error       Failed to notify ProjectEvaluationListener.afterEvaluate(), but primary configuration failure takes precedence. Mivebo      1   
Error       java.lang.IllegalStateException: buildToolsVersion is not specified.    Mivebo      1   
Error        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:176) Mivebo      1   
Error        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:606) Mivebo      1   
Error        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10$1.call(BasePlugin.java:572)  Mivebo      1   
Error        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10$1.call(BasePlugin.java:569)  Mivebo      1   
Error        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:55) Mivebo      1   
Error        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:47) Mivebo      1   
Error        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.execute(BasePlugin.java:568) Mivebo      1   
Error        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.execute(BasePlugin.java:565) Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:93) Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:82) Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:44) Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:79) Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:30) Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)    Mivebo      1   
Error        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)    Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:67)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:61)  Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:529)  Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:90)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:42)  Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$2.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:125)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:122)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99) Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93) Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)  Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:82)  Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)  Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28) Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43) Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28) Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:81)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:46)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37) Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34) Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)    Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)    Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60) Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72) Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41) Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246) Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)  Mivebo      1   
Error        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)   Mivebo      1   
Error        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) Mivebo      1   
Error        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) Mivebo      1   
Error        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)   Mivebo      1   
Error       FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.    Mivebo      1   
Error       * Where:    Mivebo      1
```

So, before the installation of plugin the app worked on device.
I've set firebase page and setted id app, but dosn't start on device. 
I've installed also google play service plugin for cordova. But still not work.
maybe i forgot something to install ? 
Thanks for help.
My target is send push notifications from firebase on Android devices.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, all those Firebase-related plugins tend to be poorly developed or introduce build errors of many kinds, so you should avoid them like the plague.

**If you only need push notifications**, stick to the [phonegap-plugin-push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) plugin which can deliver either GCM (deprecated) of FCM (Firebase) push notifications, without much problems. Make sure you **read its documentation entirely**, because a single item you miss will cause your build to fail, or notifications not to arrive, I can certify that after many years of using it.

Last: If you are really using VS2017 for Cordova, [check out this article](https://www.andreszsogon.com/visual-studio-2017-and-apache-cordova-mobile-apps/) for some issues you will certainly encounter. I keep using VS2015 without any problems whatsoever, and apps can be deployed to both WP8 and Windows 10 Mobile.

Comment: Wou, great solutions for me. I've tested and works. Thanks.